# How to load select lists based on a datepicker selection in Oracle Apex?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a date picker, but I also have three select lists for Day, Month, and Year. How can I load those as soon as the date picker is used to select a date?

Comment: You mean to set the selected value of the select lists when you select a date from the picker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a small example: [here](http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=54687:24)

[image: page setup]

I have the standard datepicker set up, i did restrict the range of years on this one (2005-2015).

The three select lists i have filled up with static lovs: days -> 1 through 31, months -> 1 through 12 buth with their name as display value, years -> 2005 through 2015.

To set their values, i created a dynamic action on the datepicker:
[image: dynamic action properties]

3 actions are required, to set the selected value of each select list. Be aware though, this causes 3 ajax calls. But the implementation is basic and doesn't require you to write javascript and ajax callbacks.

Each action is similar to this one:
[image: set value for days select list]

- **Days:** `TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(:P24_SOME_DATE), 'DD')`
- **Months:** `LTRIM(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(:P24_SOME_DATE), 'MM'), '0')`
- **Years:** `TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(:P24_SOME_DATE), 'YYYY')`

Mix 'n Match to suit what you need. Hope this helps!

Comment: I can't get mine to work. I followed your advice, however when I select a date, the date selector box does not disappear - nor does the  value get reflected in the affected elements.

Comment: There isn't anything special about this though, i wonder. Do you have anything else working on the datepicker? Can you use firefox+firebug to see what is happening? It has to be a javascript error happening.

Comment: So Firebug shows that there is an error when I select a date on the datepicker - uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #P24_DATEPICKER_START)

Comment: So I got it to work, but the datepicker does not disappear after I select a date

Comment: that's a bit odd. Does the error really show #P24_DATEPICKER_START as unquoted? That is the jquery selector, and i'd expect apex to correctly handle that part, since it is the triggering element you define. You could try to change the Selection type to jQuery selector, and enter "#P24_DATEPICKER_START" (unquoted), see where that takes you. Alternatively, do you happen to include any sort of library, or another version than the delivered jquery libs?

Answer (score 0):

In Year range, just put the previous year nothing to do with Manual.